# How to identify if there is any incoming request in UDP Chat?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I am new to Socket programming and networks, so please help me learn.

I am creating a UDP chat application where a node can send a message to all the peers connected to a chat network.

How do I check if there is any incoming packet? If there is no incoming packet, I would like to send a packet and if there is any incoming packet, I will receive it and then send.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Below is the code:

```
while(true){        
     String sendsentence2 = inFromUser.readLine();
     String[] arg = sendsentence2.split(",");
     if(arg.length==3){
         System.out.println("File transfer initiated!!");
     }else{
         byte[] receiveData2 = new byte[40];
         byte[] sendData2 = new byte[40];
         sendData2 = sendsentence2.getBytes();
         DatagramPacket sendPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(sendData2, sendData2.length, BroadCastAddress, 9876);
         serverSocket.send(sendPacket2);
         DatagramPacket receivePacket2 = new DatagramPacket(receiveData2, receiveData2.length);
         serverSocket.receive(receivePacket2);
         String sentence2 = new String( receivePacket2.getData());                        
         InetAddress replyIPAddress = receivePacket2.getAddress();
         System.out.println("Received from " + replyIPAddress + " : " + sentence2);
     }
}
```

This way, the code waits for a user input. I need to deploy the same code on all the nodes and if the same code is deployed, every node will send a packet first and not listen to other nodes.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks in advance @saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use multi-thread programming for listen to socket and send data to socket Simultaneous

Comment: Yep. I was wondering if there was any other way around that. I created a chat application as a part of college project and was wondering if I could enhance it and all that. Thanks for clearing the confusion @AzhirAhmadi :)

Comment: you can use non-Blocking Socket